# Installing Ubuntu woes (2x SSD in RAID 0 & 1x HDD)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ssd, raid

I have unsuccessfully been attempting to install Ubuntu over the last few days. The only thing I have accomplished was corrupting my windows installation and having to recover it.

What I know:

1. I have two SSD (128 GB each) in raid 0 and one HDD (1TB) used for storage
2. Windows is installed on the SSDs
3. I made a partition on windows partition editor located on the same drive as windows.

The laptop is an EVO15-s by OriginPC the spec page is located https://www.originpc.com/gaming/laptops/evo15-s/#tech-specs

Upon installation (from USB live image 14.04.2 LTS) The installer informs me that no OS is located so i click "Something else" (last time i just clicked ok and ubuntu replaced windows) to see the partition table (which i don't have enough rep to post here). What can I do from here. Let me know if you need more information. Willing to pay someone to get on skype and talk me through this at this point.

```
Partition table:
/dev/sdc
  free space 1MB
  /dev/sdc1 efi 536MB
  /dev/sdc2 ntfs 999665MB
  free space 1MB
```

The partition table also says "Device for boot loader installation:" and lists the following options

```
/dev/sdc ATA HGST HTS721010A9 (1.0TB)
/dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your partition table (sdc1 - efi) suggests that you are booting in UEFI mode. My experience is that the 14.04 installation (desktop or server) does not work with efi boot - at least it didn't for me. However, I found a way past it. You should be able to modify my RAID1 [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi?lq=1) to match your problem. Good luck!